# can't escape comma in value in column in data prep

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I am importing a comma delimited file into dataprep, to load into BigQuery, unfortunately, there is a comma in one of the columns, and I can't seem to be able to remove it before the file is split into columns.  I've imported the data in raw format to dataprep, and still can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: If there is a comma inside a quoted value, it should be preserved. What error message do you see?

Comment: unfortunately, its not inside a quoted value.  I don't see any errors, it loads the data, but the data is all moved over a column, post the row with the offending comma.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to do so before loading the csv file into Dataprep. If you have a file like this in Google Sheets:

[image]

and save it as a csv file the field that contains a comma is enclosed by double quotes:

```
a,b,c,d
12,quick,test,"field with, comma"
23,just,testing,"includes, comma"
4,dummy,data,"this, field"
```

This will be read fine in Dataprep. You can use your favorite language to programmatically escape those fields. If you still want to do so in Dataprep and have a csv like this instead:

```
a,b,c,d
12,quick,test,field with, comma
23,just,testing,includes, comma
4,dummy,data,this, field
```

You can import the dataset unselecting the Autodetect Structure option (raw format, like you already did). When you wrangle it into a new flow you will see the import steps on the right side. In this case click on the pencil icon on the second step to edit it:

[image]

and select which columns you want to apply the function to:

[image]

In this case I did it with reducing the number of matches to 3 but you can use an ignore case or so according to the use case. The output is:

[image]

Comment: thanks for this, I was unable to answer earlier.  I couldnt do above as the file was too large.  Ended up loading it into dataproc and running directly into bigquery from there.  Had a few issues with Dataprep as it seems to edit the date field again once you've set it to be something.